# Find and copy FORM tag

Tags: jquery

I need to find a form tag within an element and copy it. I feel I'm close but not quite there yet. He's what I've got so far:

**JS**

```
if ($('#myElement').find('form').length > 0) {
        var myFormTag= $('#myElement').find('form').html();         
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="myElement">
    <h1>
        blah
    </h1>

    <form action="blah.php" method="post">              

        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>option
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

I just need to return the opening  tag:

```
<form action="blah.php" method="post">
```

Comment: You need [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method?

Comment: You meant: ar myFormTag= $('#myElement').find('form').clone().html(); ? Doesn't seem to work either...

Comment: Just `var myFormTag= $('#myElement').find('form').clone()`

Comment: It returns [object Object]... :(

Comment: @santa see again my response. Showing in your question what do you expect helped a lot to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/omedet/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $myForm = $('#myElement').find('form').clone().empty();
  var myFormTag = $myForm[0].outerHTML.split("</")[0];
});
```

**Result:** `<form action="blah.php" method="post">`

Comment: I just need this:  <form action="blah.php" method="post"> the form tag and everything within it.

Comment: @santa I just updated it. See now please and tell me if it is ok

Comment: Thanks, but it grabs the entire HTML. I just need the opening <form> tag.

Comment: @santa"...and everything within it.". So, do you want just form tag or form tag and everything within it?

Comment: Just <form> tag but everything within the tag, such as action, method, ID if any...

Comment: @santa Ok. Updated. what about now?

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Wow, thanks. It's not as straight-forward as I assumed initially.

Comment: @santa I didnt understand what you were trying to achieve till you show in your question. That could have saved me some time :/ Happy coding!